# How do I get different fonts in dynamically-generated text boxes?

Tags: vba, ms-forms

When generating my form, I have code which looks something like this:

```
Set obj = Me.DataSetAuthor.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", fld)
With obj
    .top = top
    .Left = 5000
    .Width = 20
    .height = 18
    .ControlTipText = "search " & heading
    .caption = "U"
    .FontName = "Wingdings 2"
    .Font.name = "Wingdings 2"
    .Font.Size = 16
End With
```

In my static editor version, caption "U" with FontName "Wingdings 2" gives me the little circle with the "X" inside.  But not here, I get the "U" in font size 16.  What do I need to do to get the Wingdings 2 font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should firstly set the font name and only then the caption:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Dim obj As MSForms.Label, top As Double, Heading As String
  top = Me.top: Heading = "My header"
   Set obj = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "myLab1")
   With obj
       .top = top
        .Left = 50 'for 5000 it may go out from the form...
        .Width = 20
        .Height = 18
        .ControlTipText = "search " & Heading
        .Font.Name = "Wingdings 2"
        .Caption = "U"
        .Font.Size = 16
   End With
End Sub
```